# Identifying transparency in PDF Files from the command line

Tags: pdf, transparency

I first created a transparent pdf file using `CairoPDF()` in R:

```
library(Cairo)
CairoPDF("transparent.pdf")
plot( 1:10, (1:10)^2, col="blue", lwd=5 )
lines( 1:10, (1:10)^2 + 1, col=rgb(0, 255, 0, max = 255, alpha = 125, names = "green50"), lwd=7 )
dev.off()
```

(the R implementation always opens the device ready for transparency, even if no transparency is desired.)  then I created an opaque-only file in tex,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pdfx}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
hello.

\color{blue} ok.
\end{document}
```

StackOverflow does not make it easy to include a pdf file, but they are easy to recreate.

---

Now I want to identify reliably whether these files have any transparency.  Let me try different approaches.

verapdf isn't really primarily about transparency, but it does complain when it detects som:

```
$ verapdf --format text --verbose transparent.pdf | grep 6.4-3
  FAIL 6.4-3
$ verapdf --format text --verbose opaque.pdf | grep 6.4-3     
$
```

good.  verapdf works.

poppler now

```
$ pdfinfo transparent.pdf | egrep -i 'alpha|transp'
$
```

ok, no useful information from poppler here afaics.

next, sips.  I think this is a macos (not linux):

```
$ sips -g all transparent.pdf | egrep -i 'alpha|transparent'
/Users/ivo/Sync/teaching/global-climate-change-textbook/plots/transparent.pdf
  hasAlpha: no
```

this is a surprise.  sips thinks transparent has no alpha.  scratch sips.

imagemagick next:

```
$ identify -verbose transparent.pdf | egrep -i 'alpha|transpa'
  Filename: transparent.pdf
  Type: PaletteAlpha
  Base type: TrueColorAlpha
    Alpha: 1-bit
    Alpha:
  Transparent color: black
$ identify -verbose opaque.pdf | egrep -i 'alpha|transpa'
  Type: PaletteAlpha
  Base type: TrueColorAlpha
    Alpha: 8-bit
    Alpha:
  Alpha: srgba(255,255,255,0)   #FFFFFFFFFFFF0000
  Transparent color: black
```

The transparent file is not clearly identified as such; the opaque file has a good hint in `srgba(255,255,255,0)`, but given that I don't see it in transparent.pdf, I am not confident I can rely on this.

are there other good tools to identify transparency / opacity from the command line?  or is verapdf really my only reliable tool?